# Switching Grid Item position when screen size changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a scenario for my react up to switch order of two DIVs based on the screen sizes

In PC or widescreen browser I am expecting the content should be like this

[image]

But in Mobile screen or in vertical layout displays it should be like this

[image]

As you can see, the item 2 position switched to top in smaller screen?

How can I achieve this in MUI?

Comment: It's just flexbox; they [also suggest](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#how-it-works) you should read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `order` prop from MUI V5.

Here is an example based on the screenshots you provided:

```
<Grid container spacing={1}>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={8} order={{ xs: 2, md: 1 }}>item 1</Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={4} order={{ xs: 1, md: 2 }}>item 2</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thats really great..